# How to change rasterlayer color?

Tags: raster, arcobjects, c#, symbology, color-ramp

I have rasterdataset in gdb. I create layer from this rasterdataset.

```
    private static void CreateLayer()
    {
        ...
        IRasterLayer rlMosaicDataset = new RasterLayer();
        rlMosaicDataset.CreateFromDataset(rasterDataset);// name in gdb

        IRasterRGBRenderer stretchRenderer = new RasterRGBRenderer();
        IRasterRenderer rasterRenderer = (IRasterRenderer)stretchRenderer;
        IRaster raster = rasterDataset.CreateDefaultRaster();
        rasterRenderer.Raster = raster;
        rasterRenderer.ResamplingType = rstResamplingTypes.RSP_BilinearInterpolation;  // smooth
        rasterRenderer.Update();
        IRasterStretch stretchType = (IRasterStretch)rasterRenderer;
        stretchType.StretchType =
            esriRasterStretchTypesEnum.esriRasterStretch_ESRI;
        stretchType.StandardDeviationsParam = 2; // what is?
        rlMosaicDataset.Renderer = rasterRenderer;

        rlMosaicDataset.MaximumScale = 0.1;
        rlMosaicDataset.MinimumScale = 500000000;
        ...
    }
```

This layer is black-and-white imagery. I'd like that its color was green and red.
(In ArcMap I can do: Layer Properties -> Symbology -> Stretched -> Color Ramp -> here I can choose strip with green, yellow, orange, red colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's for a raster classify renderer, includes applying color ramp:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000267000000

Here's stretch:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_create_a_raster_stretch_renderer/00010000026w000000/

Comment: Where can I find the explanation of this parameters: stretchType, StandardDeviationsParam and all values?

Comment: Looking like EDN (Esri Developer Network) might be the only official place. 10.0+ requires a subscription (which you may have depending on your license agreement with Esri). I did a search for the object name and found some 9.3 info: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriCarto/IRasterStretch.htm Can't guarantee it's stayed the same, but it's a start.